# window.alert() message is not centered on big screen

Tags: javascript

on a page I'm using a simple `window.alert('some message')` the windows with the message is centred on my laptop but it's not centred on a big screen. Why?

Comment: what browser? theres nothing you can do to control that.

Comment: IE11. But shouldn't the window be always centred?

Comment: its up to the browser to get that right. perhaps something is causing it to go off center.

Comment: When you say `it should always be centered` - it's better to relate to some standard. Because I believe it is not specified anywhere so every browser decides on their own. Or maybe it's just a bug in IE

Comment: [The spec does not indicate where the `alert` window should appear at all.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your browser.

If you are using the same one with the same version installed, and just duplicated the screen from your laptop to your other screen. Then it probably is a scale problem and you would have to restart the browser/reload the page.

It's nothing you could change though.

You could just make your own alert box with CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Yes, it was because the bigger screen was an extension to another monitor. I duplicated it and all is good now. Thanks for your help.